# How to insert data into postgres using []struct{} using gorm?

Tags: database, postgresql, go, concurrency, go-gorm

I have code like this:

```golang
func o(){
 var obj []struct {
        Field1      string `json:"field1"`
        Field2      string `json:"field2"`
        Field3      string `json:"field3"`
 }
}
```

I want to insert this `[]struct` into database using another concurrent function which is being declared outside of this function.
how do I insert this type of data using gorm?

Comment: Can you show some code that you've tried? Your description of what you want is very confusing so code will be best to clarify your situation, try writing a minimal reproducible example.
As it stands, no other function can access the `obj` variable since it's non-global and not returned anywhere.

Comment: Sorry but i need clue for using that in another function using go concurrency